# Get all CommitIds between two Branches (codecommit) with cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to get all commitIds between two branches, but I only get the first and the last commitId between them.

This is what I've come with so far:

```
difference = client.get_differences(
        repositoryName=repo_name,
        beforeCommitSpecifier=main_branch_name,
        afterCommitSpecifier=dev_branch_name
    )
print("difference between branch "+ dev_branch_name + " and "+main_branch_name )

print(difference)
differences = difference['differences']
for diff in differences:
 print("diff")
 print("afterBlob")
 if 'afterBlob' in diff:
   after_or_before_blob = diff['afterBlob']
   if 'beforeBlob' in diff:
            after_or_before_blob = diff['beforeBlob']
        print(after_or_before_blob['blobId'])

        blob = client.get_blob(
            repositoryName=repo_name,
            blobId=after_or_before_blob['blobId']
        )
        print("after_blob 1:")
        print(blob)
```

[I need the CommitIds like in the picture, but i only get e029... and b0ca...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC3lt.png)

I also tried to use git for this problem, git diff for example, but this code shall be placed in a AWS Lambda and git-remote-codecommit does not work for me.

What can be a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that fits my needs, although it is a little bit slow.

I searched in the wrong place for the solution. The differences just show the differences in the files not the commits itselfs.

Therefore i used GetCommit and the given ParentId recursively.

```
    def get_list_of_commits(self, client, main_commit_id, repo_name, list_commit_ids=[], list_commits=[]):
        commit_main = client.get_commit(
            repositoryName=repo_name,
            commitId=main_commit_id
        )
        parents = commit_main['commit']['parents']
        for parent in parents:
            self.get_list_of_commits(client, parent, repo_name, list_commit_ids, list_commits)
        commit = commit_main['commit']
        if main_commit_id not in list_commit_ids:
            list_commit_ids.append(main_commit_id)
            list_commits.append(commit)
        return list_commit_ids, list_commits
```

If someone knows a better answer i would be glad to hear it.